# text echo not executing in html browser for php member login system

Tags: php

When opening this php in my browser, the form works fine. But i am not able to execute the text echo:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC etc etc>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Customer Login | CG Printing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    $form = "<form action='login.php' method=post'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='user'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login'/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>";

    if ($_POST['loginbtn']){
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if ($user){
            if ($password){
                echo "$user - $password <hr /> $form";
            }
            else
                echo "You must enter your password. $form";
        }
        else
            echo "You must enter your username. $form";
    }
    else
        echo $form;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone please help me with this, I have no idea where I am going wrong and why the echo isn't outputting to my browser

Answer (score 1):

You forgot opening quote in method assigning:

```
method=post'
```

should be

```
method='post'
```

try to change.

Comment: OMG thanks, been working on this for hours. Such a silly mistake. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it should be outputting to your browser, and it probably is - just not where you might expect it to or see.

Try viewing the source of the page in your browser, and using Find (ctrl + f) to see if any of those statements are in the source.

Answer (score 0):

first `method=post'` should be `method='post'`

second `$_POST['loginbtn']` should be `isset($_POST['loginbtn'])`

third `session_start()` should be before any command... at the top of your script..

fourth `$user` should be `!empty($user)`

fifth `$password` should also be `!empty($password)`

add these changes and let me know....

Comment: Plus i believe his else syntax lacks a "{" in each case.

Comment: @itachi, You will get downvote for that comment , as i got for my answer lol.

Comment: I tested to see if its an alternative syntax but it throws a parse error. I am sure that else should properly bracketed with '{' too.

Answer (score -1):

Close braces appropriately.

```
if ($user){
            if ($password)
            {
                echo "$user - $password <hr /> $form";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "You must enter your password. $form";
            }
          }
        else
          {
            echo "You must enter your username. $form";
          }
       }
        else
       {
        echo $form;
       }
```

Comment: This may not be the whole answer but it resolves a part. Atleast it shouldn't get downvote. +1 from me.

Comment: I am surprise why OP or others aren't getting parse error. Can you check it too?

Comment: It's perfectly ok to leave braces out of one-liners (although not a good practice). There is no practical difference between this and the OP's code.